# Date Comparsion not working in Access VBA

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to compare two dates.

But the temp always returns true.

Can you explain where i am going wrong

```
temp = (Format(CDate("27-Aug-09"), "dd-mmm-yy") > Format(CDate("07-Jul-12"), "dd-mmm-yy"))
```

Comment: Format() Returns string. You will need to convert it back to date to compare. Why do you need to apply Format?

Answer (score 0):

You're *formatting* the values according to `dd-mmm-yy` - which is actually the format they're in to start with. So you're *just* comparing the strings "27-Aug-09" and "07-Jul-12"... at which point "2" is later than "0", so the comparison finishes really quickly.

I suspect you can just get rid of the `Format` calls, to compare the dates:

```
temp = (CDate("27-Aug-09") > CDate("07-Jul-12"))
```

That's assuming that `CDate` can handle the input, of course. (I expect that part is fine.)

If you *really* want to compare strings, you need to convert the dates into a naturally sortable format, e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd`.